# negative lookahead in R regex

Tags: regex, r

I have a textual locality:

```
locality <- "NEAR HAENA BEACH PARK, N 22 13 W 159 34 500 meters from coast"
```

I would like to extract only the coordinates from this string, and not include "500" as that is not part of the coordinates; it refers to the distance from the coast.

I've written this more generalized regex command to extract coordinates with a similar pattern, and at the end I have a negative lookahead so that numbers that are actually distances are not included.

This works:

```
> capture <- gregexpr("([0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+)?(\\$O)?(\\s)?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+(\\')?(\\$O)?\\s([0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+(\\')?)(?!\\sMI\\b|KM\\b|M\\b|MILES|KILOMETERS|METERS)", locality, ignore.case = TRUE, perl = TRUE)
> regmatches(locality, capture)
[[1]]
[1] " 22 13"  " 159 34"
```

But I have left out the North and West references. If I want those N and W letters to be picked up, this no longer works properly:

```
> capture <- gregexpr("(N(\\s|\\b)|S(\\s|\\b)|E(\\s|\\b)|W(\\s|\\b))([0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+)?(\\$O)?(\\s)?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+(\\')?(\\$O)?\\s([0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+(\\')?)(?!\\sMI\\b|KM\\b|M\\b|MILES|KILOMETERS|METERS)", locality, ignore.case = TRUE, perl = TRUE)
> regmatches(locality, capture)
[[1]]
[1] "N 22 13"      "W 159 34 500"
```

In other words, by adding just `(N(\\s|\\b)|S(\\s|\\b)|E(\\s|\\b)|W(\\s|\\b))` at the beginning of the regex, the lookahead no longer works. I thought the lookahead only applied to the piece in parentheses immediately before it.

To expand on this, I have incorporated one suggestion from the comments, and have included a number of variations on this locality, that I would want this regular expression to be able to handle.

```
locality <- c(
            "NEAR HAENA BEACH PARK, N 22 13 W 159 34 500 meters from coast",
            "NEAR HAENA BEACH PARK, N 22 13 45 W 159 34 23 500 meters from coast",
            "NEAR HAENA BEACH PARK, N 22 13 12.32 W 159 34  500.4 meters from coast",
            "NEAR HAENA BEACH PARK, E 22 13 S 159 34 500 meters from coast",
            "NEAR HAENA BEACH PARK, N 22 13' W 159 34' 500 meters from coast",
            "NEAR HAENA BEACH PARK, N 22 13' W 159 34' 500 km from coast"
            "NEAR HAENA BEACH PARK, N 22 13' W 159 34' 500 distance from coast"
            )


regex <- "[NSEW]\\b([0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+)?(\\$O)?(\\s)?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+(\\')?(\\$O)?\\s([0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+(\\')?)(?!\\sMI\\b|KM\\b|M\\b|MILES|KILOMETERS|METERS)"

> capture <- gregexpr(regex, locality[1], ignore.case = TRUE, perl = TRUE)
> regmatches(locality[1], capture)
[[1]]
[1] "N 22 13"  "W 159 34"

> 
> capture <- gregexpr(regex, locality[2], ignore.case = TRUE, perl = TRUE)
> regmatches(locality[2], capture)
[[1]]
[1] "N 22 13"  "W 159 34"

> 
> capture <- gregexpr(regex, locality[3], ignore.case = TRUE, perl = TRUE)
> regmatches(locality[3], capture)
[[1]]
[1] "N 22 13"  "W 159 34"

> 
> capture <- gregexpr(regex, locality[4], ignore.case = TRUE, perl = TRUE)
> regmatches(locality[4], capture)
[[1]]
[1] "E 22 13"  "S 159 34"

> 
> capture <- gregexpr(regex, locality[5], ignore.case = TRUE, perl = TRUE)
> regmatches(locality[5], capture)
[[1]]
[1] "N 22 13'"  "W 159 34'"

> 
> capture <- gregexpr(regex, locality[6], ignore.case = TRUE, perl = TRUE)
> regmatches(locality[6], capture)
[[1]]
[1] "N 22 13'"  "W 159 34'"

> 
> capture <- gregexpr(regex, locality[7], ignore.case = TRUE, perl = TRUE)
> regmatches(locality[7], capture)
[[1]]
[1] "N 22 13'"  "W 159 34'"
```

Looks like several aspects aren't working. In the 2nd locality, the seconds are not getting picked up. Also, the lookahead should not have affected the last locality, but it does (but that might be the same problem as with the seconds).

Comment: That looks a lot more complicated than it needs to be.  Won't this work? `([NS] \\d+ \\d+) ([EW] \\d+ \\d+)`

Comment: In this case, yes that does work, but I'm trying to write this to be much more flexible, for example here there is just degrees and minutes, but there could also be seconds, and there could be decimals, and they could be in a different order, etc...

Comment: How is `(\\s|\\b)` different from `\\b`? The pattern, `N(\\s|\\b)|S(\\s|\\b)|E(\\s|\\b)|W(\\s|\\b)`, should be `[NSEW]\\b` right?

Comment: That's true. I'm still learning how regex works. Incidentally, using your suggestion solves the problem this post is about!

Comment: @PierreLafortune: The space following the letter has to be consumed, so `\s` is the one we need (or `\s+`).  We definitely don't need both.  @Pascal, how about some examples?

Comment: @AlanMoore there is no difference between the two.

Comment: @PierreLafortune: You mean, no difference between `\s` and `\b`?  There's no *similarity*!  Most importantly, `\b` doesn't consume any characters, and `\s` does.

Comment: I meant no difference between `"(\s|\b)"` and `"\b"`, but that isn't totally accurate. While spaces are included as non-word characters in boundary, it is consuming

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try this

```
location_N <- which(strsplit(locality, "\\s")[[1]]=="N")
stringr::word(locality,location_N,location_N+5)
```